# Assigning value to char string using pointer to struct

Tags: arrays, c, function, pointers, struct

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//structure defined
struct date
{
    char day[10];
    char month[3];
    int year;
}sdate;

//function declared
void store_print_date(struct date *);

void main ()
{
    struct date *datePtr = NULL;
    datePtr = &sdate;

    store_print_date(datePtr);          // Calling function
}

void store_print_date(struct date *datePtr)
{
    datePtr->day = "Saturday";           // error here
    datePtr->month = "Jan";              // same here

    datePtr->year = 2020;
}
```

Comment: Please use `strcpy()` to copy a string. Anyway `char month[3];` is not big enough to hold a 3-character (and null-terminated) string.

Comment: its showing error on datePtr where i have added the error comment
....and error is saying "expression must be a modifiable lvalue"

Comment: `"Saturday"` resolves to a pointer but  `datePtr->day` is an array. You can modify `datePtr->day[0]` etc., but not `datePtr->day`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `strcpy()` method to copy the string into the character array (note the comments):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// structure defined
struct date
{
    char day[10];
    char month[4]; // +1 size 'cause NULL terminator is also required here
    int year;
} sdate;

// function declared
void store_print_date(struct date *);

int main(void) // always return an integer from main()
{
    struct date *datePtr = NULL;
    datePtr = &sdate;

    store_print_date(datePtr); // Calling function
    
    return 0;
}

void store_print_date(struct date *datePtr)
{
    strcpy(datePtr->day, "Saturday"); // using strcpy()
    strcpy(datePtr->month, "Jan");    // again

    datePtr->year = 2020; // it's okay to directly assign since it's an int
    
    printf("%s\n", datePtr->day);     // successful
    printf("%s\n", datePtr->month);   // output
}
```

It'll display:

```
Saturday  // datePtr->day
Jan       // datePtr->month
```